# increment variable on submit to update mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP(loving it already)
I have a form that looks up a table that sends 'golf hole' info back and allows a golfer to input their score of the hole.  Problem I have is that I can present the first hole by looking up the hole_detail table but then cant figure out how loop through the table for hole 2, 3.....18 when the form is submitted.  I have searched stackoverflow but cant find anything that specific about it.  I have tried an if statement, if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) to try increment the $hole_id. Am I completely going about it the wrong way? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include ('../scripts/dbconfig.php');
# get the most recent course name:
$get_course_name = mysql_query("SELECT course_name FROM comp ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 1");
$show_course_name = mysql_fetch_array($get_course_name);

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$hole_id =1;
else {
$hole_id = $hole_id + 1;
}
}

# get the hole yardage and SI from most recent selected golf course:
$get_course_detail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `course_detail` WHERE course_name = '". $show_course_name['course_name'] . "'");
$show_course_detail = mysql_fetch_array($get_course_detail);
$get_hole_detail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `course_detail`,`phoenix_hole` WHERE Course_ID = 6 AND hole_id = $hole_id");
$show_hole_detail = mysql_fetch_array($get_hole_detail);


?>
</head>
<body>
<table width="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td width="40"><?php echo $show_course_name['course_name'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20">HOLE <?php echo $show_hole_detail['hole_id']?></td>
    <td width="5"> PAR <?php echo $show_hole_detail['hole_par'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20">Yards</td>
    <td width="20">S.I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow"><?php echo $show_hole_detail['yellow_yards'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $show_hole_detail['hole_si'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td border="1px" bgcolor="white"><?php echo $show_hole_detail['white_yards'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $show_hole_detail['hole_si'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="red"><?php echo $show_hole_detail['red_yards'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $show_hole_detail['hole_si'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>

</p>
<form id="game_form" name="game_form" method="post" action="game_form.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td><b>Hole Shots</b></td>
      <td><input name="hole_shots" type="text" class="textfield" id="hole_shots" maxlength="2" size="3" ></td>
      <td><b>Putts</b></td>
      <td><input name="putts" type="text" class="textfield" id="putts" maxlength="2" size="3"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Next Hole" align="center" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please pay attention - your SQL statements are vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: thanks Ramis Wachtler, this isn't in production yet. Security will be applied before it is released into the big bad world :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$hole_id`, in this scenario, will *always* be `1`, because when a user clicks the `Submit` button, `$_POST['Submit']` will always have a value. What you should do instead is have `$_POST['Submit']` contain the value of `$hole + 1`. PHP is not going to "remember" what `$hole_id` was last time around; it's up to you to remind it. As soon as a request is sent to the browser--unless you're using *sessions*--PHP forgets everything about that request (HTTP is "stateless").

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $hole_id = (int)$_POST['Submit'];
} else {
    $hole_id = 1;
}

# other code here

?>
You are on hole #<?php echo $hole_id; ?>.
<form>
    <!-- form stuff here -->
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $hole_id + 1; ?>">Next hole</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and got the following                                                       Fatal error: Call to undefined function int() in game_form.php online 16.  line 16 is $hole_id = int($_POST['Submit']);   thoughts?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Should be `(int)$_POST['Submit']`. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks Todd, that works a treat, I need to add some logic for when the golfer finishes hole 18 (visit the 19th? lol)

Comment: Glad I could help! Would you mind accepting it as the answer? As for the 19th hole problem, you could check for `$hole_id == 19` in your code and then print out a final score or something.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a hidden field that keeps the hole number and you can increment it from php.